# Reload TableView After Deleting, Adding, or Modifying Firestore Document and Paginating Results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving documents from Firebase Firestore and displaying them in a table view. From the table view I want to be able to delete and add items. I also modify documents from the item detail view. I'll focus on my issues deleting items for this question though. I'm getting paginated results with my query by using the last snapshot to only get the next set of items. I'm also using a listener to get realtime updates for when items are modified. The issue with deleting is how to I handle it correctly? What I currently have deletes items just fine but then doubles the remaining rows in the table view.

```
var items = [Item]()
    var itemQuery: Query?
    var lastSnapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot?

func getItems() {
    if lastSnapshot == nil {
            itemQuery = Firestore.firestore().collection("items").whereField("collection", isEqualTo: self.collection!.id).order(by: "name").limit(to: 25)
        } else {
            itemQuery = itemQuery?.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot!)
        }

        itemQuery!.addSnapshotListener( { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                return
            }

            if snapshot.documents.last != nil {
                self.lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last
            } else {
                return
            }

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let docName = document["name"] as? String
                    let docId = document.documentID
                    let docImages = document["images"] as? [String]
                    let docCollection = document["collection"] as? String
                    let docInfo = document["info"] as? String
                    let docQuantity = document["quantity"] as? Int
                    let item = Item(id: docId, name: docName!, collection: docCollection!, info: docInfo!, images: docImages!, quantity: docQuantity!)
                    self.items.append(item)
                }
                if self.items.count >= 25 {
                    self.addFooter()
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
}

func deleteItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemToDelete = items[indexPath.row]

        // Delete images from storage
        for url in itemToDelete.images {
            let store = Storage.storage()
            let storageRef = store.reference(forURL: url)
            storageRef.delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Image file deleted successfully")
                }
            }
        }

        Firestore.firestore().collection("items").document(itemToDelete.id).delete() { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Item deleted")
            }
        }
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfRows(): \(items.count)")
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemNameLabel.text = item.name

        if item.images.count > 0 {
            let thumbnailUrl = item.images[0]
            cell.itemImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: thumbnailUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "photo"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
                cell.itemImageView.roundCornersForAspectFit(radius: 10)
            })
        } else {
            cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "photo")
        }

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print("Items before delete: \(items.count)")
            deleteItem(at: indexPath)
            // items.removeAll()
            // tableView.reloadData()
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            print("Items after delete: \(items.count)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the deployment target is iOS 13+ the most efficient solution is `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`

Comment: There's quite a bit of code there but when deleting an item there are generally two ways to handle it. 1) Delete the item in Firebase and when your app receives a delete event, remove the item from the datasource within that closure and then update the UI (refreshing the tableView with tableView.reloadData). Option 2 is a manual approach where you delete the item from Firebase, ignore the event thats generated and manually remove the item from your datasource, then refresh the tableView. If this is a multi-user app, option 1) is preferred so other users will also get the delete event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property Observer to handle your `tableView.reloadData()`

```
var items = [Item]() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

what it does above is whenever variable `items` is modified, it will trigger `didSet {}` block of code.

Hope is will answer your question.

Comment: This doesn't really help because I'm using the last document snapshot for paginated results.

Comment: This isn't really a good idea. If you append 25 items to that array, the tableView will reload itself 25 times. Add 100 items to the array and that will be 100 re-draws. That's going to cause flicker and a weird UI experience. What should happen with tableViews is populate the dataSource array fully, and *then* redraw it one time.